# Website is not responding for 1 hour after django fab deploy: Nginx + uwsgi + AWS + Django

Tags: django, amazon-ec2, uwsgi, fabric

Website is not responding for 1 hour after fab deploy. Home page is responding but when click on login or example.com/admin it is not responding.

Stack: Django + Mysql + Nginx + uwsgi + AWS server (load balancing)

It was working previously for every deploys to the server, the website faster. But from few days the website is not working after deploy to server.

These are the details about the server configuration. Let me know if you need further details. Please help me.

Nginx Conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
cat nginx.conf
    user www-data;
    worker_processes  1;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

    events {
      worker_connections  1024;
    }


    http {

      include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;

      set_real_ip_from  0.0.0.0/0;
      real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;

      default_type          application/octet-stream;
      keepalive_timeout     10;
      client_max_body_size  20m;
      sendfile              on;
      gzip                  on;
      send_timeout 3600;
      # Directories
      client_body_temp_path  /usr/local/example/tmp/client_body/  2 2;
      fastcgi_temp_path      /usr/local/example/tmp/fastcgi/;
      proxy_temp_path        /usr/local/example/tmp/proxy/;
      uwsgi_temp_path        /usr/local/example/tmp/uwsgi/;

      # Logging
      access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;


      server {
        listen      80;
        server_name www.example.com;
        charset     utf-8;

        rewrite     ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
      }

      server {
        listen      443;
        server_name www.example.com;
        charset     utf-8;

        set $my_host $host;
        if ($host ~ "\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+") {
            set $my_host "www.example.com";
        }


        # SSL
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/example.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/example.key;

        # Django admin media.
        location /media/admin/ {
          alias /mnt/example/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/;
        }

        # Your project's static media.
        location /media/ {
          alias /mnt/example/releases/current/example/media/;
        }

        # Your project's static media.
        location /static/ {
          alias /mnt/example/releases/current/example/static/;
        }


        # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
        location / {

          uwsgi_read_timeout 1200;
          uwsgi_send_timeout 1200;
          uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3031;
          include     uwsgi_params;
          uwsgi_param HTTP_HOST $my_host;
          proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
          proxy_read_timeout 300s;

        }
      }
    }
```

Nginx Log /var/log/nginx/nginx.log:

```
2015/07/08 14:17:35 [error] 9970#0: *6673 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: ip address, server: www.example.com, request: "GET /accounts/login HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://127.0.0.1:3031", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/login/"
```

EDIT:
1. Ubuntu user is having the permissions on my deployed files.
2. uwsgi configuration file:

```
ubuntu@ip-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx:/etc/init.d$ cat uwsgi
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          uwsgi
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: starts the uWSGI server
# Description:       starts uwsgi using start-stop-daemon
### END INIT INFO

# Author: XXXXX
#

# Do NOT "set -e"

# PATH should only include /usr/* if it runs after the mountnfs.sh script
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
DESC="uwsgi daemon"
NAME=uwsgi
DAEMON=/usr/local/bin/$NAME
DAEMON_ARGS="-x /etc/uwsgi.xml -d /var/log/uwsgi.log"
PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME

# Exit if the package is not installed
[ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0

# Read configuration variable file if it is present
[ -r /etc/default/$NAME ] && . /etc/default/$NAME

# Load the VERBOSE setting and other rcS variables
. /lib/init/vars.sh

# Define LSB log_* functions.
# Depend on lsb-base (>= 3.0-6) to ensure that this file is present.
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

#
# Function that starts the daemon/service
#
do_start()
{
   # Return
   #   0 if daemon has been started
   #   1 if daemon was already running
   #   2 if daemon could not be started
   start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON --test > /dev/null \
       || return 1
   start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON -- \
       $DAEMON_ARGS \
       || return 2
   # Add code here, if necessary, that waits for the process to be ready
   # to handle requests from services started subsequently which depend
   # on this one.  As a last resort, sleep for some time.
}

#
# Function that stops the daemon/service
#
   #   0 if daemon has been stopped
   #   1 if daemon was already stopped
   #   2 if daemon could not be stopped
   #   other 
   #   0 if daemon has been stopped
   #   1 if daemon was already stopped
   #   2 if daemon could not be stopped
   #   other if a failure occurred
   start-stop
   #   0 if daemon has been stopped
   #   1 if daemon was already stopped
   #   2 if daemon could not be stopped
   #   other if a failure occurred
   start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --retry=TERM/30/KILL/5 --pidfile $PIDFILE --name $NAME
   RETVAL="$?"
   [ "$RETVAL" = 2 ] && return 2
   # Wait for children to finish too if this is a daemon that forks

  -daemon --stop --quiet --retry=TERM/30/KILL/5 --pidfile $PIDFILE --name $NAME
   RETVAL="$?"
   [ "$RETVAL" = 2 ] && return 2
   # Wait for children to finish too if this is a daemon that forks

  if a failur
   #   0 if daemon has been stopped
   #   1 if daemon was already stopped
   #   2 if daemon could not be stopped
   #   other if a failure occurred
   start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --retry=TERM/30/KILL/5 --pidfile $PIDFILE --name $NAME
   RETVAL="$?"
   [ "$RETVAL" = 2 ] && return 2
   # Wait for children to finish too if this is a daemon that forks

  e occurred
   start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --retry=TERM/30/KILL/5 --pidfile $PIDFILE --name $NAME
   RETVAL="$?"
   [ "$RETVAL" = 2 ] && return 2
   # Wait for children to finish too if this is a daemon that forks
```

Comment: What user has permissions on your deployed files? What options/configurations are you using to run uwsgi?

Comment: Thanks schillingt for responding. 
1. The ubuntu user has permissions 644 for /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and 755 for /etc/init.d/uwsgi/ and on deployed files ubunut user is having 755.
2. Updated the question with uwsgi conf file.
Please let me know if you need further information and provide me a resolution. Thanks.

Comment: I meant the command or config file for you to start up the uwsgi process. Not uwsgi's base configuration.

Comment: Hi  sir, I use following commands to stop uwsgi service: sudo /etc/init.d/uwsgi stop, 
To start uwsgi service: sudo /etc/init.d/uwsgi start,
To restart nginx sudo service nginx restart,
uwsgi log file: sudo tail -f /var/log/uwsgi.log